# Google disabled allow less secure apps option, how do I make JavaMailSender work now?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jakarta-mail

I have a springboot app that uses Java Mail Sender, google sees that as a less secure app so it's no longer allowed to access the account used to send emails, what can I do? I've seen a video where it's shown that if you turn on 2 step verification you can generate passwords for certain apps, but once I have generated one I don't know how I'm supposed to submit it from the spring project. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, you have to enable 2 tep verification, then generate a password for mail on windows pc, and paste said password in your code replacing the one for the google account, hope this will be useful for others